# Get Unable to obtain an object lock on "null".; org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException:

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, openjpa

This is a Spring application with Roo and the exception thrown by a simple finder function like:

```
 TransactionRate.findAllTransactionRate(TransactionRate.java:1)
```

The exception only happens to `TransactionRate` entity but not the other 20 entities. I am pretty sure their is no other entityManager is reading/editing on the entity so that table should not be locked. The persistent.xml looks clear.

I used to have similar issue but just remember the solution is to change something else in configuration(like persistence.xml), really cannnot recall details.

Please share any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there are three new fields added to the entity but not updated in database schema, hence the exception from Openjpa, leave this answer for the record.

Answer (score 4):

I just got this exception in because i had a typo in @Table and was therefore referencing a SQL table which did not exist. I figured this out because deeper in the stack, i got the message "Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

Hope this answer helps somebody who comes to this page looking for answers.